# Expectation/Variance of SO(n)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, haar-measure

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $G = SO(n)$ for the group of rotation matrices on $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $n \geq 2$. Consider the Haar measure $\mu $ on $G$, and let $e_i$ denote the standard unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Evaluate the following integrals:
$$ E_{ij} := \frac{1}{\mu(G)}\int_G(e_i \cdot Ue_j)d\mu (U)$$
$$ V_{ij} := \frac{1}{\mu(G)}\int_G|(e_i \cdot Ue_j) - E_{ij}|^2d\mu (U)$$
$E_{ij}$ and $V_{ij}$ give the expectation and variance, respectively, of the $(i,j)$th entry of a randomly chosen rotation matrix $U$.

**My attempt:**
I want to use this result about orbital averages: 
$$ \frac{1}{\mu(G)}\int_{SO(n)}f(U_x)d\mu (U) = \frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})}\int_{S^{n-1}}f(y)d\sigma (y)$$
where $x \in S^{n-1}$ (i.e. an arbitrary unit vector) and $f: S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$.

In the case of $E_{ij}$, we have
$$ E_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})}\int_{S^{n-1}}(e_i \cdot y) d\sigma (y) = \frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})}\int_{S^{n-1}}y_i d\sigma (y) =0$$
For $V_{ij}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\mu(G)}\int_G|(e_i \cdot Ue_j) - E_{ij}|^2d\mu (U) =\frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})} \int_{S^{n-1}} |e_i \cdot y|^2d\sigma (y) \\
=\frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})} \int_{S^{n-1}} |y_i|^2d\sigma (y)$$
How do I proceed from here in evaluating this interval over the unit sphere? Any advice or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Notice that the last integral is independent of i, by rotation invariance. Now sum them up over i.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for the hint! So would this be correct? $$ \frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})} \int_{S^{n-1}} |y_i|^2d\sigma (y) = \frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})}\frac{1}{n} \int_{S^{n-1}} \sum_{j=1}^n|y_j|^2d\sigma (y) = \frac{1}{\sigma(S^{n-1})}\frac{1}{n} \int_{S^{n-1}} 1d\sigma (y) = \frac{1}{n} $$

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.